# Self creating workbook with automatic save in new created folder

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have an Excel form that I need really often with other file names and changed data in the forms. I need to write code that creates a folder and saves the Excel file in it with the changed text in the form. (the text is in another Excel file)

What I have:

- I have an Excel file with a list of names, numbers and text that I need to fill in my empty form.
- I have a form where I have to write that stuff in, at the moment manually.

I know how I could get my data in my form, but I don't know how I can change the data so it kinda loops through and saves it.

I know how to save an Excel file but I'm not sure if its the best way, because I don't need any macros in the freshly saved form.

The end result should be that all the Excel forms  get saved in a path that the user decides or where the Excel macro file is in. The Excel files should be in a folder that has the same name as the form.

Plese help me with ideas how I can realise this.

---

I found this code to create folders but I'm not sure how I could bind it in that it saves only the files in that have the same name.

```
Sub MakeFolders()
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
  Set Rng = Selection
  maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
  maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
  For c = 1 To maxCols
    r = 1
    Do While r <= maxRows
      If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
        On Error Resume Next
      End If
      r = r + 1
    Loop
  Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Show your code and explain what *particular* problem you need help with.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i have no code because i don't know which functions i could us. atm my idea is that I do it half automatic with dropdown list and vlookup functions.

but this still costs so much time

Comment: Start with recording a macro and improve from there. SO is neither a place where other people write code for you, nor is it a replacement for working your way through a tutorial.

Comment: my major prolem is that i don't know how i can kinda loop through the different names..

Comment: Ok, please edit your original post to include the following: